# Set ng-show in directive

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

how is it possible to use the ng-show -variable in the directive?

Update 2:

It´s quite complicated so just added a few things more to explain what I am doing:

Controller (just the showBox):

```
$scope.showBox= false;
```

the index.html

```
<div class="box-two" myDir="showBox" ng-show="showBox">
    show only when showBox is true
</div>

<div class="panel panel-primary fixed-panel" my-dir data-update-method="'routePanelUpdate'">
    Here is the content
</div>
```

and the directive:

```
myApp.directive('myDir', function () {
    return {
        restrict: 'A',
        scope: {
            showDirective: '=myDir',
            updateMethod: '=', // this togheter does not work
        },
        link: function (scope, element, attrs) {

            this.routePanelUpdate = function (element) {
                //here the box should be visible

                scope.showDirective = true;
            };

            this[scope.updateMethod](element);
        }
  };
});
```

As you can see I have a update-method in scope, and it calls the method when the panel routePanel is on focus (as element in link). And in the method routePanelUpdate I want to visible the showBox.

How can I use the  hidden property here?

Comment: What exactly is your desired result?

Comment: I want to set  showBox = true in the directive

Comment: By passing a value into the directive? Because I see you have "updateMethod" but it is not hooked up to anything. In the outer html calling the directive `<div class="box-two" my-Dir ng-show="showBox">` what is showbox? is it a varaible you are trying to pass in?

Comment: No, this was something else entirely.I updated the code. Yes  the showbox is a variable. How can use this in the directive

Comment: Ok, but you need to clarify your questions if you want some help, adding code that is not really relevant with the same variable names is confusing. Are you trying to toggle an ng-show inside the directive, and then pass it outward? You want `showBox` that it outside the directive to be passed in and used inside the directive code for an ng-show? is that correct?

Answer (score 0):

If your goal is to pass `showBox` into your directive then all you need to do is add it to your isolate scope like so

```
scope: {
   showBox: "="
},
```

then add it on the html to the directive

```
 <div class="box-two" my-Dir showBox="showBox">
```

Now inside your directive, you will have access to to showbox. The "=" binds a local/directive scope property to a parent scope property. So changing it in the directive would change it outside and visa versa.

Comment: @MinasMinas You can just add ng-show="showBox" too.  showBox="showBox" is how you pass in the variable to the directive.

Answer (score 0):

You are going to define a directive with an isolated scope, so, you can't access to the `showBox` variable defined in the `MCtr` controller...

try to use:

```js
angular
  .module('test', [])
  .controller('MyCtrl', function($scope) {
    $scope.panels = [
      {
        id: 1,
        text: 'Panel One',
        hidden: false
      },
      
      {
        id: 2,
        text: 'Panel 2',
        hidden: true
      },
      
      {
        id: 3,
        text: 'Panel 3',
        hidden: false
      },
      
      {
        id: 4,
        text: 'Panel 4',
        hidden: true
      }
    ];
  })
  .directive('myDir', function() {
    return {
      restrict: 'A',
      scope: {
        panel: '=myDir'
      },
      link: function(iScope, iElement, iAttributes) {
        iScope.panel.hidden = false;
      }
    };
  });
```

```css
.foo {
  background: lightseagreen;
  width: 40%;
  margin: 5px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  float: left;
  color: #fff;
  font-weight: bolder;
  line-height: 50px;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>

<article ng-app="test">
  <div ng-controller="MyCtrl">
    <div ng-repeat="panel in panels"  my-dir="panel" class="foo" ng-hide="panel.hidden">  
      <span ng-bind="panel.text"></span>
    </div>
  </div>
</article>
```

Comment: this looks good. but i do not have any click event. how can I use it without function(event)

Comment: Instead of using iElement.bind>iScope.$apply... you should use directly:
iScope.showDirective = false;

Comment: it´s not working. I do not have any error, but it is stll not working.

Comment: past your full example please

Comment: pls check the code on top. I edit it in part "Update"

Comment: Why you are using  my-Dir instead of my-dir (all lowercase?), even html is case insensitive, you should have some problems with angular parser...

Comment: ok. I now where the problem is. Actually I have panels where I also defined the directive myDir. It seems like, that i can use the directive only once. but I need it many times. What would be the solution?

Comment: The problem is that you are sharing the same boolean variable to all panels, so, if you hide one of them, of course, you are hiding all of them...

Try to map each panel with its own *hidden* property and then operate on it!

Comment: what do you mean by hiddden property? can u give pls an example. I am new in ng.

Comment: i've made a refactoring of the snippet, see it!

Comment: I don´t define the panels in the Controller. Pls check the code above. In the scope I have also a updateMethod . Can this be a problem with the hidden property thing?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/94256/discussion-between-hitmands-and-minas-minas).